# How to retrieve configurable properties in main method in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Below are my application.properties :

[image]

Below is AppConfig class:

[image]

Below is ItemApplication class:

[image]

in application.properties I purposely set wrong value in **'spring.datasource.driver-class-name'** to test my code.

When I run my code, the following is observed in the logs

2019-02-12 18:04:51,413 [main] INFO  processlog -  : appConfig : com.vsi.jobs.itemsubstitution.config.AppConfig@6e75aa0d
2019-02-12 18:04:51,420 [main] INFO  processlog -  : appConfig.swapScreenUrl: null

How to retrieve swapscreenUrl value??

Comment: You must add the images as text, between <code> tags and other corresponding tags

Comment: Use actual text, not images, for your code; the input box has formatting help for you. More generally, your Boot main method shouldn't do anything but launch the application; if you need to run tasks in the context, use `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: @chrylis If u have any link ,it will help!!

Answer (score 0):

The given code does not retrieve the `AppConfig` bean properly. It just get a new instance of the `AppConfig` using new operator. If you need to use any *spring managed beans* from the spring boot application main method,you can follow the approach given below.

```
ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(ItemApplication.class, args);
AppConfig appConfig=app.getBean(AppConfig.class);
System.out.println(appConfig.getSwapScreenUrl());
```

As a very basic practise, whenever you need to use a spring bean,let the framework provide you the bean, either by directly using the `getBean()` method of `ApplicationContext` or by using `@Autowired` annotation  or by using any other dependency injection approach.

Comment: Ajit George :-i have used @ComponentScan("com.your.package" ) in my code,just for refernce i wrote here @ComponentScan("basePackage")

Comment: @SanjayNaik Oh, the provided code was confusing. If possible please provide the actual code snippet without errors, after removing any sensitive information.

Comment: Please try to inject the AppConfig bean in any other class and check if the property value is retrieved. What I see above is you are just getting a new instance of the AppConfig class. No wiring is happening.